# About the code on Blitz++ User guide

Tags: c++, blitz++

I am a beginner for blitz library. When I try to compile the code for input and output array in Blitz++ User guide as follow:

```
#include <blitz/array.h>
#include <fstream>

BZ_USING_NAMESPACE(blitz)

const char* filename = "io.data";

void write_arrays()
{
ofstream ofs(filename);
if (ofs.bad())
{
    cerr << "Unable to write to file: " << filename << endl;
    exit(1);
}

Array<float,3> A(3,4,5);
A = 111 + tensor::i + 10 * tensor::j + 100 * tensor::k;
ofs << A << endl;

Array<float,2> B(3,4);
B = 11 + tensor::i + 10 * tensor::j;
ofs << B << endl;

Array<float,1> C(4);
C = 1 + tensor::i;
ofs << C << endl;
}

int main()
{
write_arrays();

ifstream ifs(filename);
if (ifs.bad())
{
    cerr << "Unable to open file: " << filename << endl;
    exit(1);
}

Array<float,3> A;
Array<float,2> B;
Array<float,1> C;

ifs >> A >> B >> C;

cout << "Arrays restored from file: " << A << B << C << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I always got the following errors:

```
"
readtest.cpp:(.text+0x246): undefined reference to `blitz::tensor::k'
readtest.cpp:(.text+0x26c): undefined reference to `blitz::tensor::j'
readtest.cpp:(.text+0x281): undefined reference to `blitz::tensor::i'
readtest.cpp:(.text+0x69a): undefined reference to `blitz::tensor::j'
readtest.cpp:(.text+0x6b8): undefined reference to `blitz::tensor::i'
readtest.cpp:(.text+0x981): undefined reference to `blitz::tensor::i'
"
```

Could anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: These are linker errors, not compile errors.  You are likely not including the blitz libraries in your link step.  What is your command line?

Comment: Thank you for your help,my command is 
    "g++ -O2 -static -I/usr/local/genomics/blitz -L/usr/local/genomics/blitz/lib -lblitz   -o exe_readtest readtest.cpp"

Comment: Try without the "-static".

Comment: Still not right! But thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had this very problem.  Instead of trying to use tensor::i and tensor::j, declare the following:

```
firstIndex i;
secondIndex j;
thirdIndex k;
```

You can then use them in your code directly, like:

```
A = 111 + i + 10 * j + 100 * k;
```

I know their docs say otherwise, but apparently they didn't compile their example.